# Deploying the same site N times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-deployment

With our company, we sell a service to our customers, 
this is a website which let customers enter some parameters and informations, and then, they can query a web service to get
the previous informations computed. These web sites are hosted on our servers.

We would have on our servers one database per client (dbo.Client1, dbo.Client2...) with the same schema.

And we would like to provide a different url for each client :

expl :
www.client1.service.com   www.client1.ws.com/compute 
www.client2.service.com   www.client2.ws.com/compute

But i'm wondering how to deploy easily the web services and the web site?

Do i have to deploy one web service and one website per client (with different web config)?
And maybe create multiple deployment scripts ?

Or is it possible to imagine one instance of each (web service and web site), listening on several addresses, and creating different
connection string according to the entry point of the request (is it even possible with MVC or WCF ?)

Any other idea ?

I don't know what is the best practice here.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you had a look in direction "url-rewriting"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anybody read that question one day, i solve my problem using multi-tenant solution, which allow me to deploy only one instance of the site.

The site handle the webrequest, and according to the host, connect to different database.